# Android Compressed Texture Loading (GL Extensions Missing)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures

When trying to load an ATITC, S3TC, or PVRTC compressed texture in Java on Android (`glCompressedTexImage2D`), which GL constants should be set for the third parameter?

For example...if I wanted to load a PVRTC texture that supports alpha.

Am I supposed to use a constant that describes the format (but does not necessarily have the format in the name)? ex. `GL_RGBA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has problems with this..I finally find out how to accomplish this.  After finding the extension documentation (ex. [AMD_compressed_ATC_texture](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/AMD/AMD_compressed_ATC_texture.txt)), the values of the various formats are listed under the section "New Tokens".  Only if I had scrolled down the first time I saw the page..